# need different button style on focus , clicked and normal

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How can i achieve different buttons styles when 
the button gets focus, when clicked and when it losses focus.

I need to do this in jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the css, below is the provided example.

```
<asp:Button id="btntemp" runat="server" CssClass="btnclass"></asp:Button>
```

And add this in your css

```
.btnclass {color: #FFFFFF;}
.btnclass:hover { color: #3b3b3b; text-decoration:none; }
.btnclass:active { color: #3b3b3b; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change styles on various events, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yourInputId").focus(function() {
     $(this).css("color", "red"); //or something else
  });
  //similarly
  $("#yourInputId").blur(function() {
  //do accordingly
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you convert your button to a jQuery UI button? jQuery UI will automatically take care of this. You will have to include jQueryUI script for this. Once included you will be able to get the desired behavior as follows:

ASP code:

```
<asp:Button id="btnID" runat="server"></asp:Button>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btnID").button();
});
```